# Queuing https calls

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have several http calls that all use a session id, because of this I want to start my session on the backend before these other calls are fired. In iOS I can use a NSOperationQueue and pause it until my session has started then allow the operation queue to run firing all the queued calls. This is to say that startSession never goes into the queue but the method to start the session on the backend pauses the queue so no new events can fire while I'm registering the session. What would be the equivalent on Android?

Comment: You may want to look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html. This is not android specific, but something that is available in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use the `Executor` interface that Kishore suggested, I'd also like to point out the [RequestQueue](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/RequestQueue.html) object.  You can find some examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#network).

If you're using Gradle, you can include the `volley` package, where RequestQueue resides, like so:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```